# how to use Keras model.evaluate_generator

Tags: theano, keras

I have used below data augmentation for memory saving.

```
total number of test images = 400
batch size = 128
```

when i check accuracy of testset using model.evaluate_generator, it is different with final validation_accuracy from last epoch of my model.
Furthermore, output of `model.evaluate_generator` is changed when i repeat this.

below is my code.

please help!

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        color_mode= "grayscale",
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=128,
        class_mode='categorical',)    

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        color_mode= "grayscale",
        target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        batch_size=128,
        class_mode='categorical')

#%%
hist = model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
        nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples)

scoreSeg = model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator, 400)
print("Accuracy = ",scoreSeg[1])
```

Comment: Try `shuffle=False` in `flow_from_directory` definition. Also could you provide us the predictions?

Comment: thank you very much for your reply! i will try it! and what you mean predictions?